# How can I build a string from a value and a list of values?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

[First time questioner.  I *think* that I've targeted this as an Ansible question.  If not, gentle redirection is welcome!]

Given:

```
gid: 80
ports: [80, 443]
```

where the number of ports may vary from 0 to many

I'd like to produce a string like this:

"gid:80:tcp:80,gid:80:tcp:443"

(which happens to be a FreeBSD mac_portacl rule string)

The furthest I've gotten is:

```
portacl_rules: "{{ ports | zip_longest([], fillvalue='80') | list }}"
```

Which gives me somethign like this:

```
    "msg": [
        [
            80,
            "80"
        ],
        [
            443,
            "80"
        ]
    ]
```

but:

- the gid is hardcoded, I can't figure out how to interpolate the variable value; and
- I can't translate the list of into the final string.

I can create the gid string, `gid:80` by defining a temporary variable:

```
gid: 80
_tmp_gid: "gid:{{ gid }}"
```

but since I can't interpolate a string into the fillvalue, I'm stuck.

I monkeyed around the `format` filter, but it appears to take the output string as its input and the values as its arguments, which is the inverse of my situation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  The two-step answer works, but the single step does not (in my hands...), it gives `    "rules_str_2": "gid:80:tcp:80gid:80:tcp:,gid:80:tcp:443gid:80:tcp:,gid:80:tcp:987gid:80:tcp:"`.   I can't figure out how to do a longer reply that includes all fo the info....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind pair of `set_fact` tasks, you can do it like this:

```
- set_fact:
    rules_list: "{{ rules_list|default([]) + ['gid:{}:tcp:{}'.format(gid, item)] }}"
  loop: "{{ ports }}"

- set_fact:
    rules_str_1: "{{ ','.join(rules_list) }}"

- debug:
    var: rules_str_1
```

The first task creates a list of the form:

```
[
  "gid:80:tcp:80",
  "gid:80:tcp:443"
]
```

The second task joins those items using `,`.

You can complete that in a single operation using a slightly hairier expression involving the `regex_replace` filter:

```
- set_fact:
    rules_str_2: '{{ ",".join(ports|map("regex_replace", "^(.*)$", "gid:{}:tcp:\1".format(gid))) }}'

- debug:
    var: rules_str_2
```

For that `set_fact` task to work as written, you **must** use single quotes on the outside (this inhibits the use of `\` as an escape character). You could swap the quotes, but then you would need to write `\\` instead of `\`.  Recall that `(...)` in the match expression creates a capture group, and `\1` in the replacement string expands to the value of the first capture group.

---

Putting it all together in a playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    gid: 80
    ports: [80, 443]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        rules_list: "{{ rules_list|default([]) + ['gid:{}:tcp:{}'.format(gid, item)] }}"
      loop: "{{ ports }}"

    - set_fact:
        rules_str_1: "{{ ','.join(rules_list) }}"

    - debug:
        var: rules_str_1

    - set_fact:
        rules_str_2: '{{ ",".join(ports|map("regex_replace", "(.*)", "gid:{}:tcp:\1".format(gid))) }}'

    - debug:
        var: rules_str_2
```

Which will yield the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=80)
ok: [localhost] => (item=443)

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "rules_str_1": "gid:80:tcp:80,gid:80:tcp:443"
}

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "rules_str_2": "gid:80:tcp:80,gid:80:tcp:443"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: See my comment w/ my original question, the two step version works, the single step version doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try the updated version (I had to anchor the regex so it now reads `^(.*)$`).

Comment: Ah, I see.  You edited the prose, but the "Putting it all together in a playbook" example still contains the older version (which is what I was cut and pasting).  With the anchored regexp, works great.  Thanks again!!!